# Using Auto Layout in XCode to make the entire view scale depending on the size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, autoresize

I feel like there should be an easy solution to this, I don't want to do anything incredibly complex with resizing, but have been struggling to even understand the basics of auto layout. My app can't rotate, so that isn't an issue. I just want my app to scale to whatever size the screen is. I built it on the iPhone 7 screen, but if I go to a 7 plus it should just be a bit bigger. As far as I'm aware they're the same screen ratios, so I feel like it shouldn't be that difficult of a task.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah with constraints your app should work on any screen.

Comment: Yeah I'm just so unsure of what to add. I don't need anything complex, the screen won't be rotating. I just want every single thing to scale. As if I took a screenshot of it and increased the size, everything would get bigger. I want it to look relatively exactly the same on any screen.

Comment: There's no question here. Just use Autolayout; be aware that apps don't "scale" with everything becoming larger or smaller rather they adapt to changes in display size. However, if you have a specific problem or error with constraints then post that issue with details of the problem, the current outcome and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use Constraints
Top, Left, Bottom and Right should be 0 between your subview and parent view. 
Don't set the width/height of the element unless it's not supposed to change.

Comment: I only have one main view on most of the controllers, it's not a very complex app.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

" I built it on the iPhone 7 screen, but if I go to a 7 plus it should just be a bit bigger."

What if you use a smaller screen? Are you making this app for iphone 7 only? Then your app will get rejected.

You can't make everything automatically "grow bigger" in proportion to what screen it uses.

You need to configure constraints for each view and subview to make things grow "bigger" or "smaller" proportionally.

If you have labels question is how much bigger, what font size. etc. 
If you have images, question is how much bigger, what contentmode , scaling? aspect fit? fillmode? etc.
If you have tableviews/collectionviews then you need to configure the layout for each cell by subclassing it with autolayout, and also configuring the delegate methods to return a cell size in proportion to what screensize etc.

So , my tip is basically, play around with autolayout and, test, fail, test, fail, read, read, read, test , fail, until you get a hold of everything.

Check youtube, many good clips and tutorials there. Most importantly Have patiance!!

EDIT:
If you have a "simple" app, then update your question with a screenshot where you have painted something to show what you want to achieve, or an example. And maybe we can help you achieve it. But your question is too broad to answer at this moment.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I might just have to fully learn auto layout. I just thought what I wanted was simple. If it was a smaller screen it would just resize smaller! I figured since everything would resize at the same ratio, it could be easily done.

Comment: @PhilipVasseur I strongly suggest you check Youtube clips and not try to "read" so much from beginning of your learning curve, it is much easier to watch things be done.